# Repeating a table in Fitnesse at runtime a certain number of times

Tags: fitnesse

hi I like to be able to repeat a table in my test script 'n' number of times during runtime when 'n' is the result of one of the earlier operations.

Does Fitnesse support this? There is a decorator feature in Fitnesse however it only allows repeating the last row a specified number of times but NOT all the rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of table you would like to repeat and the kind of earlier operation that would provide the repeat count? I think you will have to write some fixture code to do what you want, but I need more information about what you are trying to do.  Also your development platform: Java, .NET, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen the specific functionality you are asking about. But you could break that table out to its own wiki and then include it several times.

```
!2 Do the same thing five times.
include <TestRoot.BuildingBlocks.RepetableTable
# c-switch used to minimize code in test rendering
include -c <TestRoot.BuildingBlocks.RepetableTable
include -c <TestRoot.BuildingBlocks.RepetableTable
include -c <TestRoot.BuildingBlocks.RepetableTable
include -c <TestRoot.BuildingBlocks.RepetableTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not implement loops inside the wiki pages

So the solution is to restructure your fixture so the second table will instantiate a fixture with the number you have calculated in the previous table and run the loop inside the fixture.

An interesting [blog](http://gojko.net/2009/03/09/how-to-implement-loops-in-fitnesse-test-fixtures/) post for your problem, is not my blog so please to no accuse me of publicity.